# jQuery selector that skips all descendants (not just immediate children) of given class

Tags: jquery

My head's about to explode!

Given:

```
<div class="outer1">
  <div class="outer2">
    <div class="yes"></div>
    <div class="yes">
       <div class="me-too"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="no">
       <div class="me-not"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="no">
       <div class="me-not">
         <div class="me-not2"></div>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="no"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What is a selector applied to `outer1` that will give me all the `yes` (and `me-too`'s) but nothing under `no`?

I've tried the obvious:

```
$( 'div.outer1' ).not( 'div.no' ).stuff()
```

and also:

```
$( 'div.outer1 :not(div.no)' ).stuff()
```

but, unless I have a bug elsewhere, `stuff()` is still getting `div.me-not`'s and `div.me-not2`'s

Thanks :)

Comment: Your html is not valid, you are missing 3 </div>

Comment: ^ oops, added the closing </div>'s, thx.

Comment: You are selecting the whole `outer1`. What exactly are you wanting? Expected results are a bit vague

Comment: You could grab the outer most div, find how many children, run a loop checking the class values, or just select by class. Are either of those an option or are you wanting one selector..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using find here, sorry if that's not exactly what you are looking for. This limits to div.outer1 children. It finds everything and anything not outer2, .no or anything under a .no.

```
$( 'div.outer1' ).find(':not(div.outer2,div.no,div.no *)');
```

Comment: Not quite what I wanted, and I concluded that what I'm seeking isn't possible in a single selector.  However the :not(.... *) syntax helped me kludge my way around the problem, so I will select your answer.  Thank you.